# handling duplicates in rocksdb

Tags: database, duplicates, environment, rocksdb

I want to use rocksdb and wanted to know explicitly how does it handle duplicates.

The documentations say:

```
The entire database is stored in a set of sstfiles. When a memtable is full, 
its content is written out to a file in Level-0 (L0). RocksDB removes 
duplicate and overwritten keys in the memtable when it is flushed to a file in L0.
```

Now in the case of haiving an environment with multiple databases, I couldn't find a description.
Are the Keys, in this case, environment wide unique or would every database has its unique keys? I couldn't find a description of the behavior for the whole environment.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer to your question: there's a background process called compaction, which will periodically merge couple sst-files into a single sorted run (this sorted run could be represented as multiple sst-files, but each with disjoint key-range.)  During this compaction process, it handles duplicate keys.

Here's the long answer to your question:

RocksDB is a [LSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_merge-tree) database.  When a key-value pair is written to RocksDB, RocksDB simply creates an data entry for it and append it to a in-memory-buffer called MemTable.

When MemTable becomes full, RocksDB will sort all the keys and flush them as a single sst-file.  As we keep writing more data, there will be more sst-files being flushed, where each sst-files here usually have overlapping key-range.  At this moment, suppose we have N sst files, and there's a read request comes in.  Then this read request must check all these N sst files to see whether it contains the requested key as each sst file can have overlapping key-range.  As a result, without any process to reorganize these sst files, reads will become slower as we keep writing more data.

The process that reorganize these sst files is called compaction, which is essentially a multi-way merge sort like operation that inputs multiple sst files and outputs a single sorted run.  During the compaction process, RocksDB will sort all the keys from these input sst files, merge possible data entries, and delete data entries when it finds a matched deletion entry.

Comment: I followed this right up to the end where you say "merge possible data entries," and "delete data entries when it finds matched deletion entries." Can you maybe edit the above answer (which is excellent by the way) to explain these two sentences?